# Application update, insert data in coredata while preserving userdata without modelchange

Tags: iphone, core-data

I want to release an update for my app.

I'm stuck on how to update the existing core data database which also stores data entered by the user.
All i need to do is update a couple of records and preserve current user data. No changes are made to the model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a chunk of code that performs the update, and set a user preference value (`NSUserDefaults`) when you have done so.  Include that code in your new version, checking the preference value first.

Comment: Or store the note in the metadata of the persistent store so that it can survive a wipe of the user preferences.

Comment: Most likely case for a wipe of prefs will also wipe the apps documents folder (app reinstall).