# Core data: how to migrate core data without erasing user's data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an iphone app with core data. I pre-populate an entity called DefaultValues before user download the app from app store, he then add his own data to other entities. DefaultValues never gets changed. Now, i want to modify some data from my DefaultValues entity and add some new data to it (no change in entity schema). How do i do it??

Off course, i did some research online before asking this question. I found some links here 
[Link 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750701/migrate-update-core-data-app-without-erasing-user-data)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750614/application-update-insert-data-in-coredata-while-preserving-userdata-without-mod)

but there is no concrete answer to this question.

Should i have to perform core data versioning and data migration?? Or how should i just change DefaultValues entity without erasing users data???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for the actual migration, search for "Lightweight migration". There are some Apple docs about it, also there's a topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830079/iphone-core-data-automatic-lightweight-migration)

However, you say you use Core Data to store Default Values. You probably should not use Core Data but instead [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Use this bit of code to set a default value for a setting:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"SomeSetting"];
```

you can later get the value for `SomeSetting` like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL currentSetting = [defautls boolForKey:@"SomeSetting"];
```

Similarly, you can store strings, numbers and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: Thanks fabian789. I use core data and my DefaultValues entity has at least 50 rows in it. Now, i want to insert one more row to it, don't want to modify data model. How do i do it without erasing users data present in other entities? How NSUserDefaults would help me. Can you please explain it in more details. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question. Note that you can store **as many "rows"** as you want in `NSUserDefaults`. Obviously, my answer doesn't show how to "insert one more row", I just assumed that using `NSUserDefaults` would be better as you say your data stores "DefaultValues".